# How could I put text beside an image thats already on top of background image?

Tags: html, css, image

This is what I am trying to accomplish. That background is an image, there is another image on top of that:

[image]

I have come thus far using this:

```
<img src="https://www.vizsy.com/public/images/brandow/Landing_Page_background.png" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>      

<img src="http://www.psychiatry.emory.edu/images/cloud2.png" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 70px;"/>
```

But right now, I have trouble putting the writings beside the picture as shown.

How could one do that using only html and css?

Comment: Some code would be helpful.... but have you tried using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to build a grid to hold your contents?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the image is already ontop of a background image should not change anything.

There are two approaches to this using pure CSS the first is using absolute coordinates.
e.g.

```
#img {
      left: 40px;
      top: 40px;
      height: 80px;
      width:  80px;
         }

#textblock {
      left: 140px;
      top: 40px;
      width: 200px;
      }
```

The second is using relative positioning. Which will change dependant on the screen size.

```
#img {
      left: 10%;
      top: 10%;
      height: 5%;
      width:  5%;
         }

#textblock {
      left: 30%;
      top: 10%;
      width: 60%;
      }
```

Note: Both examples assume that your textblock has an id=textblock and your image has an id=img.

Note: If you are having trouble with "layering" (what goes ontop of what) please refer to the "z-index" CSS attribute.

**Edit:** Using your updated code and taking advantage of the width attribute in inline styling something like that could be acheived simply adding the left attribute to the width attribute to get a position for the text so that the image won't overlap the text.

```
<img src="https://www.vizsy.com/public/images/brandow/Landing_Page_background.png" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/> 
<img src="http://www.psychiatry.emory.edu/images/cloud2.png" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 70px; width:200px"/>

<p style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 270px; right:20px">some text</p>
```

Notice how the left attribute for the paragraph element is = (img left) + (img width). This means it will give a start point for the paragraph next to the image in  a way that they won't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bootstrap based solution...

Note: The image and text will automatically wrap on really small devices.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1000/afeeee?text=background+cover);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/400?text=logo"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```